# Multiple WCF Services (self hosted)

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a set of WCF Services which are hosted from within a Windows Service.

I need to run multiple instances - which is fine, I can do that using unique endpoints, however for a given instance I need to known which instance it is.

For example I might have end points:

net.tcp://localhost:9000/Customer1/MyServerFunctions

net.tcp://localhost:9001/Customer2/MyServerFunctions

When a the WCF Service is called I need to know whether it is for Customer1 or Customer2

Suggestions?

Comment: Are you wanting to run multiple instances of the same contracts? Do the above instances provide the same contract methods or are they different for different customers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your service implementation can call

```
OperationContext.Current.Channel.LocalAddress
```

to determine which customer endpoint the request came from.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I thought there must be something like that available.